# Kivy app not getting converted in a onefile format with pyinstaler in windows

Tags: python, windows, kivy, pyinstaller

Okay so I am fairly new to kivy library of python as I generally use the data science ones. So I tried to create a very basic kivy app of a calculator. I wanted to convert it into a windows onefile exe. I followed the documentation and first converted into a spec file with pyinstaller. Then I added the necessary libraries. Then I again used pyinstaller to convert it in an exe. I clearly used both `--onefile` and `-w` but it did not convert in onefile but the dist folder with many files as it generally is. I hope that I have given all the necessary information to help me out. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide at least your build command and spec file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html). Note the part that says:

> Only the following command-line options have an effect when building
> from a spec file:
>
> --upx-dir=

> --distpath=

> --workpath=

> --noconfirm

> --ascii

> --clean

Note that `--onefile` is not on that list. If you want to create a `onefile`, you should use that option when you create the `spec` file.

Comment: I tried using onefile in spec but it made multiple file in exe. Is there a possible way for making onefile in exe as I don't want to transfer all that bunch of folder to client

Comment: If you run `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`, it should create a `main.spec` file which is setup for creating a one file executable.